# c3p0 rollbacks transaction instead of committing

Tags: web-services, postgresql, jetty, commit, c3p0

I have created a `ConnectionCustomizer` which set `autoCommit` to `false` and isolation level to `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ` in `onCheckOut()`

When I perform CRUD operations on my psotgresql DB and then commit, the transaction is not committed and i can see rollbacks in pg_log (see bottom).

I have read that c3p0 default behavior is to rollback any uncommitted transaction when the connection returns to the pool. How can I really commit my transactions ?

I have written this sample code into a resource to test :

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response test(@QueryParam("userId") long userId,
                     @HeaderParam("Accept-Language") String acceptLanguage) throws NamingException, SQLException {

    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = (ComboPooledDataSource) context.lookup("jdbc/mydb");

    SimpleJdbcInsert insertTest = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
                                            .withTableName("chat")
                                            .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("idchat");
    //BEGIN transaction                                     
    dataSource.getConnection().commit();

    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
    parameters.put("idcompte", userId);
    parameters.put("idvendeur", 148);
    parameters.put("idannonce", 282);
    parameters.put("creationdate", new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance()
            .getTime().getTime()));
    parameters.put("lastmodified", new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance()
            .getTime().getTime()));

    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    m.put("idchat", insertTest.executeAndReturnKey(parameters));

    //Commit transaction
    dataSource.getConnection().commit();

    return Response.ok(m, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}
```

This resource returns me the autogenerated value :

```
{
    idchat: 101
}
```

But when I look into the table the row isn't inserted and pg_log shows this :

```
LOG:  durée : 0.019 ms, analyse <unnamed> : SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
LOG:  durée : 0.005 ms, lien <unnamed> : SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
LOG:  durée : 0.006 ms  exécute <unnamed>: SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
LOG:  durée : 0.014 ms, lien S_1 : BEGIN
LOG:  durée : 0.004 ms  exécute S_1: BEGIN
LOG:  durée : 0.222 ms, analyse <unnamed> : INSERT INTO chat (idannonce, idcompte, idvendeur, creationdate, lastmodified) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "idchat"
LOG:  durée : 0.075 ms, lien <unnamed> : INSERT INTO chat (idannonce, idcompte, idvendeur, creationdate, lastmodified) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "idchat"
DÉTAIL:  paramètres : $1 = '282', $2 = '226', $3 = '148', $4 = '2013-07-04 14:57:07.466', $5 = '2013-07-04 14:57:07.466'
LOG:  durée : 1.027 ms  exécute <unnamed>: INSERT INTO chat (idannonce, idcompte, idvendeur, creationdate, lastmodified) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "idchat"
DÉTAIL:  paramètres : $1 = '282', $2 = '226', $3 = '148', $4 = '2013-07-04 14:57:07.466', $5 = '2013-07-04 14:57:07.466'
LOG:  durée : 0.012 ms, lien S_2 : ROLLBACK
LOG:  durée : 0.030 ms  exécute S_2: ROLLBACK
LOG:  durée : 0.025 ms, analyse <unnamed> : SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
LOG:  durée : 0.004 ms, lien <unnamed> : SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
LOG:  durée : 0.006 ms  exécute <unnamed>: SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ
```

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching a new Connection from the DataSource and calling commit() on that. That's useless, as you've done no work on the new Connection. JDBC transactions are scoped per-Connection. You need to commit() on the Connection that has performed the inserts, access to which is buried somewhere in your `insertTest` object.

(Editorializing, a class called `SimpleJdbcInsert` is probably not such a great idea. JDBC inserts are pretty simple as is. Your code would be a lot cleaner if you just did the work here, or handed it off to a subsidiary function that accepts a Connection. If you are handing a DataSource, your `SimpleJdbcInsert` must be responsible for all of fetching the Connection, committing or rolling back any transactional work, and close()ing the Connection. If that object fails to close() the Connection, you have a Connection leak and will exhaust the pool. If it does close() the Connection without committing, you should not be shocked that your work was rolled back.)